# Setting CUPS defaults with lpoptions vs web interface

Tags: cups

Forgive me if this has been answered already. Please point me to the relevant post.

I am trying to use lpoptions to set the default print mode to B/W. Works fine when I use the web interface but lpoptions doesn't seem to have any effect.

My printer is a networked HP LaserJet (and is the system default) and when I do (as root)

```
lpoptions -l
```

I get a list that includes

```
PrintoutMode/Printout Mode: Draft Draft.Gray *Normal Normal.Gray High High.Gray
Quality/Resolution, Quality, Ink Type, Media Type: *FromPrintoutMode 150BestColorCMYK 150ColorCMYK 150DraftColorCMYK 150DraftGrayscaleK 150GrayscaleK 300BestColorCMYK 300ColorCMYK 300GrayscaleK 600BestColorCMYK 600GrayscaleK
```

So I expect that when I do

```
lpoptions -o PrintoutMode=Draft.Gray
```

the default colour mode should be "Draft Gray". (Yes, I have restarted the CUPS service too, in case that mattered.) Yet, when I open an application and do File->Print and check the options it still says "Color".

When I make the same change through the web interface I see the change immediately. What am I missing? Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get to the CUPS interface, it will show the installed printers. To change the defaults go to "Set Printer Options" and select the option you what to change, `colormode = Black and White`.

Otherwise, since you said your client needs to have a command line queue to do it, you could do so: `lpadmin -p {printer name} -o {ppd property}` from the console.

You can get the name which CUPS is using for the printer with a simple `lpstat -p`.

The property you'll want to set is `EFColorMode` to `Grayscale`. So a `sudo lpadmin -p {printer name} -o EFColorMode=Grayscale` may be enough.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, but my question was how to do it using command line. I already know how, and can, do it with the Web interface. :)

Comment: @ColinWu is there a _good, valid_ reason to do it from command line? What changes?

Comment: The client I'm working with wants to. :( Good enough? Having said that, a valid answer could be "it can't be done" ; however, all the documentation and Stackexchange posts I've looked at so far seem to say this is totally doable. I just haven't found the right cat to twirl yet.

Comment: @ColinWu you could try to queue your printer so: `lpadmin -p {printer name} -o {ppd}`, the PPD property you'll want to set is `EFColorMode`, so `EFColorMode=Grayscale`. `sudo lpadmin -p {printer name} -o EFColorMode=Grayscale`. With `lpstat -p` you can find the name which CUPS is using for the printer.

Comment: SOLVED: The problem is that `lpoptions` changes are only seen by command-line print programs like `lp` and `lpr`. In order for GUI programs to see the change one must use `lpadmin` to make changes directly to the ppd file. Thanks @JeffWalterz.